# A $G_δ$ subset of $2^ω$ that is homeomorphic to $ω^ω$

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set, the-baire-space

How do I show that there is a $G_δ$ subset of [the Cantor space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) $2^ω$ that is homeomorphic to [the Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $ω^ω$?

I've been given the hint to consider $G = \{x ∈ 2^ω : x\text{ is not eventually constant}\}$, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, [Brian M. Scott's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/254381) to a different question provides one method to demonstrate this.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks for the link. I've looked at the answer but I'm not familiar with all of the terms. How does showing that X (or in this case G) is separable and metrizable and not locally compact anywhere equate to a homeomorphism?

Comment: [Arthur Fischer's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/254369/89374) to a different question actually answers your question since the set of infinite words on $\{0,1\}$ with an infinite number of $1$ is the intersection of the (open) sets of all infinite words having at least $n$ occurrences of $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment to the question, a [previous answer by Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254381) provides one method to demonstrate that the particular subset $G$ is homeomorphic to the Baire space. In particular, he uses the following characterisation of the Baire space:

> The [Baire space $\omega^\omega$] is (up to homeomorphism) the unique zero-dimensional, separable, Čech-complete metrizable space that is nowhere locally compact.

He then shows that $G$ has all of these properties to conclude that it is homeomorphic to the Baire space *without* explicitly constructing a homeomorphism.

---

If you don't have this "pile-driver" handy, you'll probably have to construct the homeomorphism by hand.

First, to show that $G$ is G<sub>δ</sub>, note that $G = \bigcap_n U_n$ where $$U_n := \{ \mathbf{x} \in 2^\omega : \mathbf{x}\text{ switches between }0\text{ and }1\text{ at least }n\text{ times}\}.$$ (So $\mathbf{x} \in U_n$ iff $\mathbf{x}$ has an initial segment of the form $0^{k_0} 1^{k_1} \cdots b^{k_n}$ or $1^{k_0} 0^{k_1} \cdots b^{k_n}$ where each $k_i > 0$, and $b$ is the appropriate bit.)

To construct the homeomorphism, note that given any $\mathbf{x} \in G$, we may write it as an infinite concatenation as $$\mathbf{x} = 0^{k_0} 1^{k_1} 0^{k_2} 1^{k_3} \cdots$$ where $k_0 \geq 0$, and $k_i > 0$ for all $i > 0$. Using this we define a function $\varphi : G \to \omega^\omega$ as follows: $$\varphi ( \mathbf{x} ) = ( k_0 , k_1 - 1 , k_2 - 1 , k_3 - 1 , \ldots ).$$ 
It is not too difficult to show that this function is a homeomorphism from $G$ onto the Baire space.

---

As a final note, it is somewhat superfluous to show that $G$ is G<sub>δ</sub> since it is a theorem that any completely metrizable subspace of a completely metrizable space must be a  G<sub>δ</sub> subset of that space. That is, the existence of the homeomorphism between $G$ and the Baire space shows that $G$ is a G<sub>δ</sub> subset of the Cantor space. (Also *any* subspace of the Cantor space which is homeomorphic to the Baire space is a G<sub>δ</sub> subset of the Cantor space; *e.g*, the subspace provided in [Arthur Fischer's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254369) to the same question.)

Comment: Thanks, that was excellent. It cleared up my confusion with Brian's answer as well as answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

The required claim easily follows from general facts about metrizable spaces. The Baire space $\omega^\omega$ is [zero-dimensional second countable completely metrizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)#Properties). Since $\omega^\omega$ is zero-dimensional second countable, it can be embedded into Cantor Cube $\{0,1\}^\omega$ (see, for instance, [Eng, 6.2.16]). Since $\omega^\omega$ is  completely metrizable, it is a $G_\delta$ sibset of $\omega$ for any its embedding (see, for instanse, [Eng, 4.3.24]).

*References*

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[image]

[image]

[image]