# A subset of the Cantor set that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the Cantor set and let $A\subset\mathcal{C}$ be the set of sequences with infinitely many 0's and infinitely many 1's.

Any hint on how to show that $A$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are homeomorphic ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $n $-th block of $k +1$ consecutive appearances of the same symbol corresponds to the number $k $ in the $n $- th position?

Comment: Although the questions were different, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225104/12042) completely answers this question, as does [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/254381/12042).